# How can I correct this erroneous Jquery code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a piece of code right here. I want to change the selected word(s) in the text to bold, itallics or underlined text:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Try to select this text.</p>
</div>
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Bold" />
<button id="changeItallics">Italics</button>
<button id="changeUnderline">Underline</button>
<script>
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
     }

        var nat = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nat);
        return nat.innerHTML;
} catch (e) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    } else {
        return getSelection();
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
    $('#changeColor').click( function() {
        var mytext = selectHTML();
        $('span').css({"font-weight":"bold"});
    });
     $('#changeItallics').click( function() {
        var mytext1 = selectHTML();
        $('span').css({"font-style": "italic"});
});
     $('#changeUnderline').click( function() {
        var mytext2 = selectHTML();
        $('span').css({"text-decoration": "underline"});
    });
});
</script>
```

However, whenever I click the Bold, Italic or Underline buttons, the letters previously selected are also being transformed. How can I correct it? Did I forget something?

Comment: You are just selecting all spans

Answer (score 0):

Your code is selecting all `span` elements, causing all of them to be targetted when applying new styles.

You should instead target only the `span` element with the innerHTML matching the value returned by `selectHTML()`. Like so:

```js
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
     }
        var nat = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nat);
        return nat.innerHTML;
} catch (e) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    } else {
        return getSelection();
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
    $('#changeColor').click( function() {
        var mytext = selectHTML();
        console.log($('span').toArray());
        $($('span').toArray().filter(e => e.innerHTML == mytext)[0]).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
    });
     $('#changeItallics').click( function() {
        var mytext1 = selectHTML();
        $($('span').toArray().filter(e => e.innerHTML == mytext1)[0]).css({"font-style": "italic"});
});
     $('#changeUnderline').click( function() {
        var mytext2 = selectHTML();
        $($('span').toArray().filter(e => e.innerHTML == mytext2)[0]).css({"text-decoration": "underline"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Try to select this text.</p>
</div>
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Bold" />
<button id="changeItallics">Italics</button>
<button id="changeUnderline">Underline</button>
```

Comment: Nice. But edge case : `<p>Try to select this text this text.</p>` will not work if you select *text*. Your jQuery selector will match both as it relies solely on the text value.

Comment: I've tried this code. However, it isn't working

Comment: @MsBonniePython I've updated it. It should work now.

Comment: Tysm for the help!

Comment: @MsBonniePython No problem. If it solves your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every time you are clicking, it is adding the stylings to what this returns `$(span)`.
Now ,after a few clicks you have multiple spans. `$(span)` will return the collection and stylings will apply to all of them.

Notice you are returning the innerHTML of the span from your selecHTML function. Instead return the element and make use of it with the jQuery Selector `$()` to refer the correct `span` element.

If you want to make use of the innerHTML you can do it with your returned value.

```js
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
     }

        var nat = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nat);
        return nat;
} catch (e) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    } else {
        return getSelection();
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
    $('#changeColor').click( function() {
        var mytext = selectHTML();
       //var myTextInnerHTML = mytext.innerHTML; 
       $(mytext).css({"font-weight":"bold"});
    });
     $('#changeItallics').click( function() {
        var mytext1 = selectHTML();
        $(mytext1).css({"font-style": "italic"});
});
     $('#changeUnderline').click( function() {
        var mytext2 = selectHTML();
        $(mytext2).css({"text-decoration": "underline"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Try to select this text.</p>
</div>
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Bold" />
<button id="changeItallics">Italics</button>
<button id="changeUnderline">Underline</button>
```

Comment: Tysm for the help!

Comment: Sure, please accept/upvote this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

For bold as the example, your code is saying, get me the selected text. Do nothing with that selected text. Then for all span tags, set the font-weight css property to bold.

I don't see any span tags for the code listed.

Comment: The span element is created in :var nat = document.createElement("span");

Comment: Ok, so you have a span tag in memory, there is still no span tag on the page for jQuery to bold.